# Symfony - define variable when declaration is not compatible

Tags: php, class, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I wrote a doctrine query builder to return all transactions by one card. 
So I call the $card variable in the other function and it throws:

> Warning: Declaration of Service\SomeService::showFields(ShowMapper $showMapper, $card) should be compatible with Admin\AbstractAdmin::configureShowFields(ShowMapper $show)

As I ca't change syntax of this Admin Service or adding new instances I need  a way out.

This is main function

```
 protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper, $card->this throws an error, it can't be set here)
{

    $transactions = $this->getTransactions($card);

...etc
```

and my doctrine query:

```
 public function getTransactions(Card $card)
{
    return $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.card = :card')
        ->setParameter('card', $card)
        ->orderBy(''desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

I tried:

```
 public $cards;

public function __construct(Card $cards)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->cards = $cards;
}

$cards = $this->cards;
 $transactions = $this->getTransactions($cards);
```

but it throws

> Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that have an identifier.

Comment: Maybe you could make `$card` a variable on your `SomeService` class and use a getter/setter. That way you can first set the card on the class and then within your function you can use the getter to retrieve the card info without passing it as an argument.